# Deploying jekyll for github page blog

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

Followed the Jekyll documentation direction and pushed the folder directly under master branch and when that didn't work, also set up the gh-pages branch and pushed just the site folder contents under it. Still didn't work.

github: https://github.com/shinshinwu/shinshinwu.github.io

my _config.yml setting:

```
# Site settings
title: Anna's Chunky Bacon and Sweater House
description: Programming and all other random thoughts
baseurl: /myblog/ # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://localhost:4000" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
```

Any tips would be helpful! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your `_config.yml` is not at the root, with `source` and `destination` variables set.

But, the easiest way is to create a https://github.com/shinshinwu/myblog repository and put your jekyll blog in its gh-pages branch.

The url will still be shinshinwu.github.io/myblog and you avoid mixing Jekyll and non Jekyll things.

Comment: Wow this really helped, I knew it was some sort of referencing issues but wasn't sure what it is specifically. And this really helps to separate the settings as well. Thanks David!